# DHTMLX scheduler date and Time not saving to db

Tags: java, mysql, date, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

When I add a new event to the Calendar everything else saves except the date and time which is not saving to the database so the event will not show all together , but when I insert a row from the database it shows. I suspect that maybe the formats are wrong?

This is the format for the date

```
    scheduler.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
```

the format for mysql is the usual yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.

Anyone knows what i should do?
I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Did u checked scheduler.config.lightbox.sections,scheduler.init and all other syntax.because it should work without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using scheduler with connectors - try to enable logging for connector. It will provide code of auto-generated SQL queries, which may help to detect the reason of the problem.